# How to log redux actions out into cypress console

Tags: redux, cypress, ngrx

I'm having trouble getting cypress to correctly log each redux action being processed by our app as a live feed into the cypress console.

I had assumed that this would entail subscribing to our actions object which gets exposed to cypress through the window object using the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Component({
  selector: 'application-initialize-cypress-variables-component',
  templateUrl: './initialize-cypress-variables.component.html',
})
export class InitializeCypressVariablesComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private readonly actions: Actions) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (window.top.Cypress) {
      window.actions = this.actions;
    }
  }
}
```

Then subscribing to this object within cypress would be pretty straightforward. We would just need to cy.log everytime our app dispactched an action which could be done by adding a cy.log inside of the subscribe block on window.action

```
actions.subscribe((action) => {
      cy.log(action.type);
    });
```

This works correctly and logs out each redux action being processed as a live feed to the cypress console. The issue is that I am getting this console error which says something along the lines of: "Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise" as the actions are being logged out. This makes me think that I am doing something incorrectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be possible at all, since the Cypress commands run asynchronously in their own queue.

That means when you javascript issues a `cy.log(some-param)` call it's saying "add a log entry for some-param after all the preceding commands have run", but it's not actually executing the log at that point in time.

You *may* be able to do it with [Cypress.log()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log#Examples) instead, since it runs immediately.

```js
actions.subscribe((action) => {
  Cypress.log({
    displayName: 'action',
    message: action.type
  })
})
```

But note, the Cypress command queue and the redux action queue are both asynchronous from the Javascript of the test runner.

I think you will need something to synchronize the two, something that performs an step in the test then waits for the resulting redux action to complete.